# I want to trigger a javascript function when a div changed thru a ajax function the text

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to  trigger a javascript function when the status changed to "Upload successful".

I have no idea how to do that.

The status get after a multi file upload changed, depending on success or error.

```
            <div id="status"></div>

            $("#status").html("<font color='green'>Upload successful</font>");
```

Comment: just call the function where you're setting the status to successful.

Comment: I tried to call the function direct after the success message, I tested it with a alert(). But the alert get for every file repeated.

I add more code.

Comment: can you share the rest of your code?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, call the function after the ajax success like:

```
success: function(output) {
            if(output == 'success'){
                function();
            }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your very fast answer. Yes you understood the question perfect.

Can I add the output to "onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr)" ?

For example: onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr,output)

Is this possible? And if yes, output is a object. How to get the text out of it?

Comment: How does your php look like?